# Origine et signification d'expression "Faire monde"

Tags: grammaire, expressions, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

J'ai rencontré l'expression "faire monde" : https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/faire-monde.1430525/

Quelle est l'origine de cette expression ? Quel phénomène grammatical permet la juxtaposition d'un infinitif et d'un substantif ? Quel est le sens de cette expression ? Est-ce une expression courante ?

Comment: Faire bon accueil, faire dodo, faire débat, faire feu, faire honneur, faire loi, faire plaisir, faire signe, taire tache, faire table rase...

Comment: À 40 ans, je ne me rappelle pas avoir déjà entendu cette expression et serait bien embêté sans contexte (ou même avec) d'imaginer sa signification... Je ne suis cependant pas porté sur la philosophie donc ceci explique peut-être cela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Il s'agit d'une expression **très courante**... (elle a même eu été à la mode)... en... philosophie! Depuis au moins Heidegger, repris par Merleau-Ponty...

Ne faisant pas partie de ceux qui prétendent avoir compris Heidegger... et sachant encore moins dire si tous entendent précisément la même chose par là... (ce serait étonnant) je te renvoie sur un forum spécialisé pour ce sens.</sup>

---

Faire suivre un infinitif par un substantif n'a rien de très original en français, en particulier lorsqu'il s'agit du verbe *faire* employé au sens [III.F. du TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire) de ***paraître, sembler***

Ainsi certains aristocrates croient bon de *faire peuple* (paraître comme des gens du peuple), certains artistes ou politiques de *faire genre* (se donner un look particulier répondant à un cliché à la mode)

Pris dans ce sens (c'est à dire hors licence poétique comme c'est manifestement le cas dans l'exemple que tu cites) je comprends ce *faire monde* (beaucoup utilisé depuis peu dans les milieux écologistes) comme un synonyme d'***exister***... (1)(2)

*Faire monde* c'est donc... adopter une attitude qui sera (de préférence bien) perçue par le monde (les autres) (3)

On peut le faire suivre d'*avec*. *Faire monde avec...* Pour marquer une existence en compatibilité / connivence avec...

---

<sup>1 : hé oui! exister c'est... être perçu... comment ? oui! J'avais dit que je n'en parlerais pas...)</sup>

<sup>2 **Exister** dont l'étymologie remonte à... *venir au monde*. Mais ça... on n'y est pas pour grand-chose. Donc 1/ Tu viens au monde et existe donc passivement. 2/ tu *fais monde*... et alors existe activement.</sup>

<sup>3 : On observera, dans ce sens, la disparition très logique du sens péjoratif associé au faux-semblant des expressions traditionnelles en *faire-xyz*. De fait, que je trie mes déchets, que je fasse attention à ma consommation d'énergie pour me donner un genre alors que je ne suis pas convaincu de cette nécessité ou que je le fasse par conviction sincère... who cares! L'attitude est *"bonne"* dans les deux cas.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

On ne trouve pas cette expression dans les dictionnaires, chose bizarre, mais son utilisation est montée en flèche depuis 1980 ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faire+monde&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaire%20monde%3B%2Cc0)).

Le sens philosophique de l'expression qui est étudié dans la réponse de [user **aCoswt**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/39945/17649) ne semble pas être le seul, pas suffisant pour justifier l'importance de l'usage récent. Au lieu de « exister » on comprend « faire venir en existence », « composer », « constituer ».

- L'enjeu de l'action écologique est bien de faire monde, de composer un monde entre les humains avec les nonhumains. Une écologie décoloniale - Penser l'écologie depuis le monde ...
  https://books.google.fr › books
- Mais ce petit peuple veut « faire France » plutôt que « faire monde ». Il faudrait donc lui parler d'immigration et de frontière si l'on veut le toucher, ce que firent Jean François Copé et Nicolas Sarkozy dans leurs dernières campagnes. Chroniques du temps présent II
  https://books.google.fr › books

**I**

On se penche sur l'utilisation de l'expression dans un article sur le problème terre à terre de la pollution des océans par le plastique. C'est un article intitulé « *Faire monde avec l’irréparable* » par Baptiste Monsaingeon, dans lequel l'expression apparait plusieurs fois et pour commencer dans le titre. Une des occurrences est en forme nominalisée. On essai donc de déterminer un sens (ou peut-être plusieurs) dans le contexte de cet article. (caractères gras dus à user **LPH**)

On s'attarde d'abord sur le titre,

### « *Faire monde avec l’irréparable*

*Sur les traces des océans de plastique* »,

et on remarque qu'il est traduit en anglais par

« *Getting by With the Irreparable: Following the Traces of Plastic Oceans* ».

Selon ce possible nouveau sens,  il est question de s'adapter aux circonstances, de les  rendre supportables, d'arriver à s'en sortir.

On continue par un examen des occurrences restantes en commençant par un rappel du paragraphe.

1. N’y-a-t-il pas dans ces projets de grand nettoyage un projet au moins aussi problématique que celui qui semble en mesure de le justifier ? En l’absence de solutions de dépollution, certains subliment ces traces de la catastrophe en cours en un matériau pour nous inviter à réfléchir sur les origines bien terrestres de cette invasion plastique et pour expérimenter de nouvelles façons de **faire monde avec** nos restes.
2. Quelques années après, le projet semble en avoir inspiré d’autres, et diverses armadas de radeau détritiques ont vu le jour de Barcelone à Philadelphie 16. Se revendiquant des mouvements sociaux récents, depuis Occupy Wall Street jusqu’aux Indignados de la Puerta del Sol à Madrid, ces groupes accordent au radeau détritique une signification double à la fois poétique et politique, il a une vocation à la fois spectaculaire et heuristique : « Comment, concrètement, vivre sur les restes du monde d’avant ? » Par-delà l’aspect technique et les contraintes propres à la construction et à la vie quotidienne sur de tels navires, ces initiatives se rassemblent comme autant d’expérimentations **d’un *faire monde*** avec les océans de plastique. On retrouve peut-être quelque chose de cette façon de faire avec en observant la prolifération des populations d’halobates sericeus dans les milieux océaniques. Ces araignées d’eau ont fait de ces millions de particules flottantes autant de supports potentiels pour leur nidification, et, dans le Pacifique notamment, ont largement colonisé un territoire jusque-là inaccessible.
3. Conséquence de ce mouvement d’accumulation incessant, les océans de plastique deviennent ainsi, lentement, des fragments de ce que l’archéologue Laurent Olivier nomme l’inconscient du temps (2008). Surgissant sur le mode de la catastrophe, ils sont ces résurgences inattendues qu’il apparaît nécessaire de chasser, de tenter d’effacer : il semble toujours plus désirable de les voir disparaître, de les oublier. Mais, à l’image des populations d’Halobates sericeus, ces araignées d’eau devenues les principaux colonisateurs de nos improbables « continents », la confrontation à ces phénomènes pourrait être une occasion fertile d’imaginer les façons de ***faire monde*, d’habiter** cela même qui a été, un temps, rejeté à la frontière intérieure de notre foyer commun.

**II**

Après une lecture d'au moins quelques paragraphes importants de l'article on ne peut plus s'arrêter sur la traduction anglaise dans le titre, une traduction qui est pourtant réaliste puisque ses termes impliquent que l'on s'arrête à la considération d'intégrer le produit de la catastrophe dans un schéma d'existence viable et non comme dans le sens  se dégageant des paragraphes, littéralement, de construire un monde, de le constituer.

Il ressort de tout ce qui a été passé en revue qu'un sens de cette expression est celui de constituer une existence nouvelle à partir de quelque chose, de créer un monde, comme en particulier dans l'exemple sur la pollution, un monde construit à partir de débris de plastique (émuler des créatures marines qui tirent leur parti du plastique, créer des habitations à partir de ce plastique (idée fumeuse, je dois dire)).

Il existe de nombreuses autres sources à examiner, mais je crois qu'il vaut mieux que je n'étende pas plus le présent  exposé.